# warning EF1000. What the best way to write parameters in "IN" statement?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

EF Core 2.1 throws warnings about SQL injection. There is my code snippet where it happens

```
var query = await _ctx.Set<TABLE>()
                      .FromSql("Select * from TABLE where Artikelnummer IN (" + string.Join(',', artNum) + ")")
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .Select(z => new
                      {
                        z.Artikelnummer,
                        z.Property
                      }).ToArrayAsync();
```

where `artNum`(stands for Artikel Numbers) is array of int numbers, like [1,22,34 etc.].

I can't pass `artNum` as parameters in FromSql, because there will be **single quotes** and SQL throws an exception.

I can rewrite the FromSql to

```
.Where(x => artNum.Contains(x.Artikelnummer))
```

But I have queries that much bigger and complicated than this one, so *LINQ to Entities* isn't good in this situation.
there should be So, the question is how to rewrite this query so warning won't occur?

*LINQ to Entities* executes much longer than *LINQ to SQL*, so it's not appropriate way to solve my problem.

I investigated that concatenation causes warnings, so there should solution without concatenation.

Comment: The [documentaiton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) is quite clear about SQL injection. I guess that one of the methods mentioned there should work with `IEnumerable`s as well.

Comment: There is no method that solves my problem, because every time appear single quotes.

Comment: Have you tried using something like `_ctx.Set<TABLE>().Where(x => artNum.Contains(x.Artikelnummer)).AsNoTracking()..etc..` ?

Comment: A warning is not an error.  If you want to review the code to ensure no SQL injection vulnerability actually exists, then you can suppress or disregard the warning.  Here since you are concatenating a list of `int`, not `string` you are safe from SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find such warning in EF Core documentation. And the (sort of) funny things is that the EF Core 2.1 query translator itself does not parameterize the generated SQL `IN` values clauses. Which can be seen if you replace the `.FromSql` line of your query with

```
.Where(x => artNum.Contains(x.Artikelnummer)
```

which btw is the LINQ to Entities equivalent of your query which translates and executes just fine, so I don't know why you bother with `FromSql` in this particular case.

But anyway, you can parameterize the [`FromSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsql?view=efcore-2.1) query by including `{0}`, `{1}` etc. placeholders inside the sql string and pass values through `params object[] parameters`:

> As with any API that accepts SQL it is important to parameterize any user input to protect against a SQL injection attack. You can include parameter place holders in the SQL query string and then supply parameter values as additional arguments. Any parameter values you supply will automatically be converted to a DbParameter

In your case it could be like this:

```
var placeholders = string.Join(",", atrNum.Select((v, i) => "{" + i + "}"));
var values = atrNum.Cast<object>().ToArray();

.FromSql("Select * from TABLE where Artikelnummer IN (" + placeholders + ")", values)
```

Comment: Concatenation in FromSql causes warning.

Comment: The first argument of `FromSql` method is basically string, I have no idea what concatenation are you talking about, the method implementation has no way to know if the string was hard coded or produced with concatenating several strings. How exactly you "investigated concatenation causes warnings"?

Comment: I tried to use concatenation and single string and only in the second situation I can see warning that caused in query.

Comment: Consider providing [mcve] then. With the current code from the question I'm not getting any warning with or without technique suggested in the answer. Btw, I guess we are speaking about Visual Studio and not some 3rd party extensions like Resharper or similar? Are you getting **compile time** or **runtime* warnings? Can you post a screenshot? Also what happens if you use variable, e.g. `var sql = "Select * from TABLE where Artikelnummer IN (" + placeholders + ")";` and then `.FromSql(sql, values)` (or event your original query with concatenated string coming from variable)?