# Raw query with IN clause when using EF core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

First, sorry because my Eng not good.
And i have an issue with my query using EF core raw query

```
SELECT * FROM [Iot.Core].[dbo].[LocaleResources] WHERE [Key] IN ({0})
```

and i want pass list string as parameter

```
var inClause = new List<string>() { "Apple", "Banana", "Cream"};
```

But result from DbContext return is incorrect.

```
dbContext_LocaleResources.FromSql(_querySelectLocaleResourceByKeyAndLanguage, inClause).ToList()
```

Please help! Thanks you

Comment: Just do `context.LocaleResources.Where(x => inClause.Contains(x.Key));`

Comment: hi @juharr but i need use raw query. this's requirement of my project. thanks you

Comment: What is "incorrect"?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong data format of inClause to replace the placehoder. I figure out a way to use RawSQL with IN Clause by using `RawSqlString`.

```
  List<string> list = new List<string>()
        {
            "Apple",
            "Banana",
            "Cream"
        };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        list.ForEach((item) =>
        {
            sb.Append("'");
            sb.Append(item);
            sb.Append("'");
            sb.Append(",");
        });
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);//{'Apple','Banana','Cream'}

        RawSqlString raw = new RawSqlString($"select * from Customer where Name in ({sb.ToString()})");
        var result = _context.Customers.FromSql(raw).ToList();
```

Update:

It will always have warning if you would like to pass a list of string to `IN`.

> The SQL expression passed to 'FromSql' embeds data that will not be parameterized. Review for potential SQL injection vulnerability

A workaround is using `Or` instead of `IN`

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
        {
            "Apple",
            "Banana",
            "Cream"
        };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("select * from Customer where "); 
        list.ForEach((item) =>
        {
            sb.Append("Name='");
            sb.Append(item);
            sb.Append("' Or ");
        });
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 4, 4);
        RawSqlString sql= new RawSqlString(sb.ToString());
        var result = _context.Customers.FromSql(sql).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Xing Zou your code working for me. But i get a warning: The SQL expression passed to 'FromSql' embeds data that will not be parameterized. Review for potential SQL injection vulnerability. How to resovle it? Thanks you

Comment: You could use `string.Join(",", list.Select(x => $"'{x}'")` instead to create the comma separated string of values.

Comment: @Minh Mit,I find it will always have this warning even I try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256477/warning-ef1000-what-the-best-way-to-write-parameters-in-in-statement) if you pass list of string to `IN`clause.I update a workaround in my answer